# Ubuntu 14.04LTS won't login

Tags: login

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS dual boot with Windows 7 and completed installing all update and stuff...

I wanted to make my NTFS partitions (C: (windows 7 drive) and D:to mount automatically on startup so I used "Disks" tool available on Ubuntu and failed to make that happen...
so I change the "mount point" on the D: partition from `/media/xxxxxx` to `/`
(hoping this will make a difference) and now Ubuntu shows system problem detected and keeps logout every time I try to login...

please help me I can't use Ubuntu right now because of this and I'm a new Linux user and don't know much about what to do.

Comment: How did you change the mountpoint? By editing `/etc/fstab` or what did you do?

Comment: Desks tool? Don't you mean Disks?

Comment: Can you hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 and log in there?

Comment: I just tried that, and actually I can log in this way. but it shows only a black screen like in terminal.

Comment: That's supposed to be like this ;) Now can you please check whether there is anything about your D partition in the output of `cat /etc/fstab`?

Comment: PS:sorry for my late replay I have to restart my computer to do that

Comment: I have got this http://s15.postimg.org/rv2wkxt0b/image.jpg

Comment: any ideas what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you told me in the comments, your `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

[image]

To fix the issue, you have to edit this file. Instead of using `/` as mount point, better mount it somewhere below `/mnt`.

First boot from the installation disk, and open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Now execute

```
sudo parted -l
```

and find out which one is your installed Ubuntu's root partition. You'll need the device file of drive (`/dev/sdX`) and the partition number of your root partition (hereafter called `Y`), being formatted ext4 or btrfs.

After you found that out, use

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ububtu
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/ubuntu
```

to mount the root partition. Then chroot into the installed system:

```
sudo chroot /mnt/ubuntu
```

Now first execute

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/somename
```

To create the directory to mount it on. Of course, you can use something else than `somename`... Now open `/etc/fstab` in a text editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

navigate to the line starting with `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` and go to the `/` right before `auto`. Instead of `/`, put the mountpoint there, so it will look like

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/<uuid> /mnt/somename auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
```

Save the edits with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and exit the text editor with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. Now exit the chroot environment with

```
exit
```

For the future: **Never** mount anything that is not the running system's root partition at `/`. In general, don't use directories that already exist. Use a subfolder in `/mnt` for manual or permanent mounting instead.